# No such file or directory error on executing script

Tags: shell, ubuntu, bash

I use `GNU Emacs 24.3.1` on `Ubuntu 14.04` and I have a bash script: `~/path/to the/script/test.sh`. As you see the path has `space` character. Script has a simple content:

```
ENTRY=`zenity --password --username`
```

When I try to run script from `Emacs` by `C-c C-x`(execute script option from `Sh-Script` menu), without marking any region, I got this error:

```
/bin/bash: ~/path/to: No such file or directory

Comint exited abnormally with code 127 ...
```

But when I try to run that from bash, it runs normally:

```
~/path/to\ the/script/test.sh
```

So I'm sure the problem is in about `space` character in path of script. Also I do not want to change the path (by removing `space` and for example replacing it by '_') because it is a part of a nested/linked content manager system and changing it may cause a big problem. Is there a way to solve this problem without changing path of script?

Comment: What command do you have bound to `C-c C-x`? That's not a key which is customarily bound to some common command.

Comment: Sounds like you need to shell-quote. I suspect that this is a duplicate question, but I don't have the time now to search.

Comment: @db48x I did not understand what you mean:`What command do you have bound to C-c C-x?` but I did not mark (select) any text in script. Also I edited my question, please see it again.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. You're in sh-mode, which does indeed bind a command to the `C-c C-x` shortcut (specically the `executable-interpret` command). It looks like this command has a bug which should be reported with `M-x report-emacs-bug`, but we can probably also work around. I'll make the work-around into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `ctrl-c ctrl-x` is bound to `execute-interpret`, then the system should prompt you with the command to run, suggesting as a default `/path/to the/script/test.sh` as a default. Edit this default value to put single quotes around the whole thing.

A different way would be to change the command to be run to `./test.sh`. I suspect that when you say `But when I try to run that from bash, it runs normally.` you are actually running this command, not the one emacs offers you by default.

You might consider adding some setting of [file variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html#File-Variables) to the end of the file, e.g.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 echo Hello there
 ....

 # Local Variables:
 # mode: sh
 # executable-command: "'/path/to the/script/test.sh'"
 # End:
```

This will query you if you want to set the variable when you load the file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the workaround that I mentioned:

```
(defun db48x/shell-quote-arg-list (args)
  (mapcar 'shell-quote-argument args))

(advice-add 'executable-interpret :filter-args 'db48x/shell-quote-arg-list '(name escape-command-name))
```

This tells emacs to run the `db48x/shell-quote-arg-list` function on the argument list any time anyone calls `executable-interpret`. This gives us a change to escape any spaces in it before it's passed off to the original function.

This works quite well; any spaces or shell metacharacters you give to `executable-interpret` are escaped, and everything works quite well.

There is one downside, however. The next time you run `executable-interpret`, it will reuse the same value again as the new default script to run. However, it saved the value after we escaped it, so if you use it as-is it will be escaped again. A more complex set of advice needs to be applied to get the right behavior, probably an :around function that escapes the argument, calls the original function, and then overwrites the variable holding the previous command with the unescaped version.

Edit:

Here's the better method I mentioned:

```
(defun db48x/executable-interpret-escaped (original-func command)
  (funcall original-func (shell-quote-argument command))
  (setf executable-command command))

(advice-add 'executable-interpret :around 'db48x/executable-interpret-escaped '(name escape-command-name))
```

Comment: Excuse me because I'm beginner. Where I have to do edit/add `defun  ...`?  What must be values? Any link that describe is preferred. Also does that saves the value and use it for all other scripts?

Comment: Add them to your ~/.emacs/init.el file. This file is run on startup and is where most of your customizations will end up.

Comment: @db48x, The problem with this approach is now you can no longer pass arguments to the script. They are merged into the filename. What I think is needed is to raise a bug report to change the `(or executable-command buffer-file-name)` to `(or executable-command (shell-quote-argument buffer-file-name))`.

Comment: Yes, that's reasonable as well. Harder to define advice for though.

Comment: @db48x I think the proposed way by ` icarus` is simpler, at least for beginners. But thank you for your reply!

Comment: @hasanghaforian, you're welcome!